# $scope variable is treated as string - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have declared and initialized few Scope variables and want to access them dynamically, but when I try to access a variable from html file, that variable is treated as a string.

JS Code-

```
$scope.abc3txt = "Hello";
$scope.abc2txt = "hello everyone";
$scope.abc1txt = "hello 123";
```

There is a number with every variable like 3,2,1 between abc"number"text.

I want to access the variable value according to the number in my html file.

HTML code-

```
<h4>{{abc+a.status+txt}}</h4>
```

a.status has some value like 1,2 or 3.

This prints like "abc3txt" in html, instead of returning the initialised value of "$scope.abc3txt" variable.

Please someone help..

Comment: Use an array or object! Variable variables are madness. `$scope.abc[3] = { txt: 'Hello' }`, or just `$scope.abc[3] = 'Hello'` or probably just `$scope.abc = ['Hello', 'hello ...', ..]`. This can be accessed unambiguously.

Comment: Not yet @kiro112.. Going to try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it can be done with `$scope` directly. A way would be to save those values in an object:

```
$scope.values = {
   abc3txt: "Hello",
   abc2txt: "hello everyone",
   abc1txt: "hello 123"
};
```

And in you view you could access them like this:

```
{{values['abc' + a.status + 'txt']}}
```

EDIT:
The best alternative would be to use the controllerAs syntax. Suppose you have in controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.abc3txt = "Hello";
vm.abc2txt = "hello everyone";
vm.abc1txt = "hello 123";
```

Then in your view:
`{{vm['abc' + a.status + 'txt']}}`

Comment: From HTML you'll need an intermedairy field. Of you'll need to use **controllerAs** syntax to be able to do that.

Comment: Can we use ";" semicolon inside object, Only comma can be used right ?

Comment: Yes, to separate fields from one another in an object, you need to use comma, if you mean that with your question!

Comment: Thanks for the help @SpartakLalaj for making me understand things.. It worked!!

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely shouln't use variables namese that way, in javascript...
Consider using arrays...
Something like this should help:

In the controller:

```
$scope.a = {};
$scope.a.status = 2;
$scope.abctxt = [ "hello 123", "hello everyone", "Hello" ];
```

And, in the template:

```
<h4>{{ abctxt[a.status - 1] }}</h4>
```

Comment: Just because you used 1, 2, 3 for the names of your variables, so I supposed your array was 1-based. If it is 0-based (0,1,2,...), you can avoid `-1`...

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic generation of variable names in the way you are seeking is, in all possible perspective, a very, **very**, **SUPER-VERY** bad practice, and this regardless of the support (or lack of it) a language may have. Having said that, arrays is the right way to go.